# Compiling TP-LINK TL-WN725N v2 Drivers - make errors

Tags: networking

I would like to compile and install the drivers myself for **my TP-LINK TL-WN725N v2**

The official source is https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

My Pi version info is

```
uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I ran the following cmds whilst connected to my Pi over ssh(PuTTY)

```
wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu/archive/master.zip
mkdir wifiSetup
mv master.zip wifiSetup
cd wifiSetup
unzip master.zip
ls

control_ap core hal include os_dep rtl8188eufw.bin
COPYING dkms.conf hostapd-0.8 Makefile .md rtl_hostapd.conf
```

I then tried to compile with the following

```
make -f Makefile
```

Returns error

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build M=/home/pi/wifiSetup/rtl8188eu-master modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Do I have to place the master.zip files in a certain directory before calling the `make` cmd? Currently I placed the master.zip contents in any random directory thinking it wouldnt matter, aslond as MakeFile was read and had files relative to this location

Answer (score 1):

The README for that package mentions that you need the kernel headers installed.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi
```

Unfortunately, that may not leave a link in `/lib/modules/3.12.28+`.  To check, `ls /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build`.  It should give a list,

```
arch  include  Makefile  Module.symvers  scripts
```

If not, and instead just says "No such file" or gives just the path you gave it:

```
sudo rm /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi /lib/modules/3.12-1-rpi/build
```

(You don't need the first `rm` if the previous `ls` returned "No such file"). This should at least get you past your current error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried to compile a simple driver that I wrote but I managed to fix it using the previous answer. Just as an observation, I replaced the last command

sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi /lib/modules/3.12-1-rpi/build

with

sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-rpi /lib/modules/3.12.28+/build